# Initializing a pointer with 'this' keyword. Does it create new instance? Using it make my program thread-safe or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, object, oop, thread-safety

Here is a singleton design pattern. I am trying to make the given code thread safe, using thread_local.
First of all, I need to know how the given instantiation of the pointer with 'this' works.

`File : Myclass.h`

```
class Student
{
   public:
   Student();
   int x;
   private:
   static Student *globalStudent;

};
```

`File : Myclass.cpp`

```
Student *Student::globalStudent = NULL;

Student::Student()
{
    assert(globalStudent == NULL);
    globalStudent = this; // How this works? Does it creates an instance?
}
```

And after making it thread-safe,

`File : Myclass.h`

```
class Student
{
   public:
   Student();
   int x;
};
```

`File : Myclass.cpp`

```
thread_local Student *globalStudent = nullptr;

Student::Student()
{
    assert(globalStudent == NULL); 
    globalStudent = this; 
}
```

Does it make my program thread-safe? If not, then what should I do?

Comment: similar code has been posted before. What is the purpose of it? Why do you use a global `Sutdent*` ?

Comment: The global pointer is thread safe.  What it points to is thread safe as long as the object is not shared across threads.  For "WHAT SHOULD I DO?" I recommend avoiding threads if possible.

Comment: btw, please do not SHOUT.

Comment: frankly, it is a little odd that you are using advanced features (globals, threads, `thread_local` ) but are lost when copying a pointer. Do you know what happens in `int x; int* p = &x;` ? Is there an additional `int` created?

Comment: You don't get a singleton by using one instance per thread (`thread_local`). Second, singletons are well-known software design patterns, so you'll find lots of info. However, it is also a so-called anti-pattern, i.e. there are some serious downsides. If anyone teaches it as a good thing, be wary!

Comment: The exact comment `// How this works? Is it creates an instance?` was in a [previous deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71296918/initializing-a-pointer-object-with-this-can-anyone-explain-how-it-works) under a different username.

Comment: I did not made my question clear last time. And currently, I am curious, how can i convert a single pattern thread safe. Thread local, have a copy of object for every thread called.

Comment: @zenitsu7, What is `globalStudent`? Why does the single-threaded program only have one? and why do you think it's OK for the multi-threaded version to have more than one? There is, in general, no easy answer to the question, "how can I add threads to this program...?"

Comment: the meyers singleton is thread safe. Your "singleton" is not idiomatic and not really a singleton. Someone can copy the `student` and completely bypass your `globalStudent`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> globalStudent = this; // How this works?
> ```

`this` is a special expression that yields a pointer to the object whose member function is being called. This assignment makes the assigned pointer point to the object whose member function is being called.

> Does it creates an instance?

No, assigning a pointer doesn't create an instance.

> DOES IT MAKE MY PROGRAM THREAD-SAFE?

A singular change cannot make an entire program thread safe.

But, the change does make it safe to call `Student::Student()` from multiple threads without synchronisation. It's important however to consider that each thread will point to a different instance. Hence this is by definition not a singleton.

This is an unnecessarily complicated way to implement the singleton pattern. (And singleton is sometimes an anti-pattern, so consider carefully whether it's appropriate).

Comment: Thanks, I had my doubts. I never used 'this' keyword in such a way. I mainly used during overloading, or in derived classes. But code implemented in such a way was new to me.